# Where is the scrollback location for the mac terminal?

Tags: mac, terminal, terminal.app

Title says all. (the one when you use the scrollwheel to see the old commands and results)

I do not wish to clear it for sure as some data I have lost is within some old scrollback.

Comment: I don't even have a Mac, but did you try the Page Up / Page Down buttons (represented by symbols with arrows on a page on Mac keyboards)? Or maybe it's an option hidden somewhere within the application menu on the top of the screen. Or the window's contextual menu (ctrl-click). With Macs, things are often where you least expect them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somewhere in memory or maybe the data files in `~/Library/Saved Application State/com.apple.Terminal.savedState/`. (`sudo opensnoop -n Terminal` shows what files are accessed by Terminal.)

I don't know any way to see the scrollback history of old tabs. This shows lines that are cleared with `C-l` but not ⌘K:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to history of window 1'
```