# Prevent terminal scrollback from being saved to disk?

Tags: security, terminal, history

My question is the opposite of [Where is the scrollback location for the mac terminal?](https://superuser.com/q/529657/504387)

I want to generate a google authenticator code.  This will show a QR code on the command line which I can scan with my phone to add the TOTP generation seed.

I can do this while logged in to the server on which I'll be using the TOTP code.  (This is for SSH login with a second factor for authentication.)

However, I want to ensure the QR code is NOT saved anywhere on my laptop, since it contains the secret seed for TOTP generation.

So, I want to either use a different terminal setup that doesn't *ever* save the terminal scrollback history to disk, or disable this *completely* (temporarily) so that I can generate the QR code, have it shown on my screen, scan it with my phone, and then close the window on my computer and be certain that the QR code is not stored anywhere on my computer at all, not even if file recovery software were to be used.

How can I do this?

Comment: Which terminal app are you asking about, and are you sure it is saving scrollback to disk at all? Most terminal apps don't.

Comment: @egmont those five comments add up to a decent answer...want to post it?

Comment: Yeah I should have done it in the first place :) Moved to an answer, slightly extended; also deleted these comments above.

Comment: Please see newly added correction below.

Answer (score 3):

First, you have to make sure that you either don't have a swap, or it's encrypted. A fragment of a process's memory can be swapped out at any time and then it's on the disk.

Second, you need to know that it's pretty much impossible to wipe out all remains of the handled data from RAM, it goes through many steps of copying, it might be there in `malloc()`'ed area of the terminal or even of the `ssh` client, or released back to the OS without wiping. Or in the memory of the display server (X11/Wayland), the video card's memory, etc. If an attacker somehow gains access to your RAM (your running computer) then it's hopeless to protect your data.

Therefore, by making sure that your terminal doesn't write the scrollback to disk, you're only protected against the situation when your computer is shut down and then it's stolen. And then still only if your swap is encrypted. Also I assume that your main disk isn't encrypted because then it wouldn't be an issue.

I don't know what other terminals do, but I know what VTE (used by GNOME Terminal, GNOME Console, Tilix, Terminator, Xfce4-Terminal, Guake, RoxTerm and many others) does. It writes the scrollback to disk (not yet when it's onscreen, only after it scrolls out [see correction below]), but encrypts that data and explicitly wipes out the encryption key from memory as soon as that terminal tab or window is closed (it might remain in the memory if it crashes for some reason (which it pretty rarely does) or if it's killed).

Let me also mention that I don't think any terminal writes out to disk the contents that are onscreen [see correction below]. Those bits can change extremely quickly, writing them to disk would be bad for performance and bad for disk lifetime, and couldn't serve any purpose (I mean: Would it then be cleared from memory, and read back from disk whenever needed? Terribly expensive. Or would it also be kept in memory? Then why write it out already?) Even if a terminal writes out its scrollback, it almost certainly only does that for data that scrolls out of the normal viewport of the terminal. If you close your terminal with the QR code (as you say you're planning to), rather than reusing it for new commands, letting the QR code scroll up to the scrollback buffer, then almost certainly no terminal writes it to the disk (unless you set up some sort of logging or debugging in the terminal).

Quite a few terminal emulators support either one-off options (e.g. specify in the command line not to have a scrollback buffer), or multiple profiles (define one profile with no scrollback buffer, start up a new terminal with that profile for the QR code). This provides an additional protection: if you accidentally follow the QR code by executing a command that produces long output, your QR code still doesn't end up in the scrollback buffer.

You might also encapsulate the tool that prints the QR code in a wrapper script, to reduce the chance of mistakenly scrolling it up to the scrollback buffer. The wrapper code could for example wait for you to press Enter, then move the cursor home and overwrite the screen with spaces or such. But beware: the `clear` operation is implemented in some terminals by erasing the onscreen contents in-place, while in some others (e.g. VTE) by scrolling them out to the scrollback buffer! Another thing you can do is to switch to the alternate screen (`tput smcup`; back to the normal screen: `tput rmcup`). The alternate screen doesn't have a scrollback buffer, whatever you scroll out there should be lost for good (but do double check your terminal's behavior). Note that leaving the alternate screen doesn't clear it, its contents are back if you switch back to it, so you should clear it before switching away. You can further combine this with a terminal emulator profile that starts this script as its custom command, or a command that starts up a terminal emulator with specific settings to run this script only. This way you can be overly protective that the QR code won't be scrolled out, but even if it is, there's no scrollback buffer configured.

But, again, unfortunately none of these protect you from the QR code presumably lingering around in RAM at many places in many different formats for a long time. I can't think of a protection against that.

---

Correction:

VTE writes the contents of the "regular area" to disk when you resize the window horizontally. As usually, it encrypts the data before writing.

Why does it do that, you may ask. On resize it rewraps (reflows) the lines, which is an extremely complicated code. The "regular area" is in one format (in memory), while the scrollback is in another format (on disk). Rewrapping both would have required to implement the same essential rewrapping logic for two very different kinds of data structures, making sure that it operates identically on the two, and without problems around the point where the two are stitched together. Instead, the already existing code which converts from one format to the other is used to convert the "regular area" to the scrollback's format (thereby also stored on disk), then rewrapping is performed on that single data structure, finally the last screenful of that is converted back to the in-memory format.

This code only kicks in if the terminal's width changes (no need for rewrapping if only the height changes), and only for the normal screen (the contents of the alternate screen aren't rewrapped).